# when a css ul li item extends past ul, how to match dynamic width of an ul

Tags: html, css

JSFiddle of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/td6szj3o/

/
i have an ul li with standard text items per each li. the list is dynamic, so sometimes each content li is smaller than the set `width:100%` of the container it sits in, but sometimes a li item has text that expands past the width:100% of the container. instead of forcing the text to the next line, i am wanting to keep the long text extending past the ul. currently that works fine with little extra css styling to the ul.

[image: showing normal ul li list with background of li per each odd numbered li item]

using this method, i see a bottom scroller that pops up under the ul and allows me to scroll to the right to view the rest of the li content. that is fine for me and i want to keep this.

however i am introduced to a problem trying to keep the alternate li background color that is so popular and often standard with most data output in an unordered list. since the css of the li that sits in the ul is `width:100%`, and the ul itself stops at the `width:100%`, the li extends only as far as the ul width. but the problem is while the text is extending past the li, it technically is outside of the `width:100%` of the ul itself, and thus the background color on the li stops wherever the ul width ends.

[image: the view when we have output that is longer text than normal]
[image: showing where the li stops, but text extends, thus li background stops where li stops]

i am trying to come to a solution that would work in all browsers, that will allow the ul to have the li item extend to the full width of the longest content of any li. the closest i have gotten is using `display:table-header-group`, but unfortunately it does not expand to `width:100%` when i have small text content inside the li.

i could simply add a `min-width:300px` or something to the ul, and this would fix my problem. but that isn't going to cut it when user is on a smaller device or monitor size unfortunately. when i use `min-width:100%` that does not solve the issue either. i have used every combination of `display:XXX` that i can come up with, and when i `float:left` anything in the ul or li, that breaks the view either for the smaller text ul output, or the longer text ul output, or both at the same time.

any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. i am looking for a solution that works in all latest versions of Chrome, FF, Safari, etc; and sticks to a css solution.

please note i intentionally have left word-wrapping off of the css. i do not want the text to go to the next line, but instead keep being displayed horizontally across the ul.

below is the html/css i am using:

```
<ul>
<li>dynamic li item would be here; nothing crazy</li>
</ul>

.sidebar ul {
    position:relative;
    max-height:55vh;
    min-height:10em;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}
.node-list{
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
.node-list li{
    padding: .15em .5em .15em .35em;
    margin:0;
    border-left: solid 2px transparent;
    max-width:100%;
    width:auto;
}
.node-list li a{
    color: rgb(73,73,73);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.node-list li:nth-of-type(2n){
    background-color: rgb(242,242,242)
}
.node-list li:nth-of-type(2n-1){
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255)
}
```

Comment: We need a minimal working code snippet as well

Comment: jsfiddle added as well

Comment: Great....and of all combination your tried, you missed one :) so I posted that one for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `sidebar ul` to `display: inline-block` and change from `width: 100%` to `min-width: 100%`

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td6szj3o/2/)

Stack snippet

```css
.sidebar ul {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 55vh;
  min-height: 10em;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100%;                 /*  changed property */
  display: inline-block;           /*  added property   */
}

.node-list {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.node-list li {
  padding: .15em .5em .15em .35em;
  margin: 0;
  border-left: solid 2px transparent;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.node-list li a {
  color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.node-list li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242)
}

.node-list li:nth-of-type(2n-1) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="node-list">
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Two of the nation's top intelligence officials repeatedly refused to say Wednesday whether President Donald Trump asked them to intervene in or downplay the FBI's ongoing Russia investigation, though they said they have never felt pressure to act</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Two of the nation's top intelligence officials repeatedly refused to say Wednesday whether President Donald Trump asked them to intervene in or downplay the FBI's ongoing Russia investigation, though they said they have never felt pressure to act</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Two of the nation's top intelligence officials repeatedly refused to say Wednesday whether President </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, when you add `display:inline-block` that removes the horizontal slider when this ul is put into a small div. try putting this ul into a 400px wide div and you will see the result. i will update my fiddle to represent that environment

Comment: @HollerTrain Like this? ... https://jsfiddle.net/td6szj3o/20/ ... where I added an extra outer `div`

Comment: @HollerTrain Or like this? ... https://jsfiddle.net/td6szj3o/21/ ... where I set it to the `sidebar` ... and as you can see, both these samples work

Comment: ok so i do your solution is working, however on the application i must have some parent div that is forcing the horizontal slider to be removed. thoughts on what could be force-removing it?

Comment: @HollerTrain Have your tried `overflow: hidden`? ... If you can't make it work, post a fiddle for me and I'll have a look

Comment: this application has some sort of JS script that adds a styled scroll to the ul. if i add `min-width:100%;display:inline-block` that will remove the JS scroll. then i change `overflow:hidden` to `overflow:overlay` in the parent div, and now a normal browser based scroll shows up

Comment: @HollerTrain Okay, well you need to do as I showed (which works exactly how you asked) if you don't want to start messing with script and/or fixed width's. If there is an app on top of this, that mess things up, you need to control it, one way or the other, which I also think is beyond this question

Comment: @HollerTrain The best would be to chose an answer that best solves the original question and the post a new with the extra requirements you now described.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file remove the `no-wrap` and add `break-all` to the li:

```
.node-list{
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
.node-list li{
    padding: .15em .5em .15em .35em;
    margin:0;
    border-left: solid 2px transparent;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

JS Fiddle that I believe is the solution https://jsfiddle.net/td6szj3o/14/

Comment: Not sure why you -1 me. You have no wrap in your css.

Comment: i -1 you because your solution was not close to resolving the problem. secondly, i intentionally have `white-space: nowrap;` in the code as i want to keep the horizontal scroll in the list

Comment: @BillyFerguson upvoted (just cos OP doesn't appreciate your efforts doesn't mean they go unnoticed)

Comment: @BillyFerguson no bother.. onwards and upwards!! :)